# Flag to ignore serialization of property build_runner

Tags: dart, flutter, json-serialization

Is there a way to ignore the serialization of a property within a JsonSerializable class?

I'm using build_runner to generate the mapping code.

One way to achieve this is by commenting the mapping for that specific property within the .g.dart-file though it would be great if an ignore attribute could be added on the property.

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'example.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Example {
  Example({this.a, this.b, this.c,});

  int a;
  int b;

  /// Ignore this property
  int c;

  factory Example.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ExampleFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ExampleToJson(this);
}
```

Which results in

```
Example _$ExampleFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Example(a: json['a'] as int, b: json['b'] as int, c: json['c'] as int);
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$ExampleToJson(Example instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{'a': instance.a, 'b': instance.b, 'c': instance.c};
```

What I do to achieve this is by commenting the mapping of c.

```
Example _$ExampleFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Example(a: json['a'] as int, b: json['b'] as int, c: json['c'] as int);
}

Map<String, dynamic> _$ExampleToJson(Example instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{'a': instance.a, 'b': instance.b, /* 'c': instance.c */};
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Depreciation warning

```dart
@Deprecated(
      'Use `includeFromJson` and `includeToJson` with a value of `false` '
      'instead.',
    )
this.ignore,
```

## **NEW**

As @Peking mentioned
The new way is to specify whether to add or remove in fromJson and toJson functions

```dart
@JsonKey(includeFromJson: true, includeToJson: false)
```

## **OLD:**

As @Günter Zöchbauer mentioned
The old way is by passing `ignore: true` to the `JsonKey`

```dart
@JsonKey(ignore: true)
String value;
```

Answer (score 67):

**Update**

This has changed to

```dart
@JsonKey(includeFromJson: false, includeToJson: false)
```

**from before**

Add `@JsonKey(ignore: true)` before the field that you don't want to include

```
 @JsonKey(ignore: true)
 int c;
```

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/blob/06718b94d8e213e7b057326e3d3c555c940c1362/json_annotation/lib/src/json_key.dart#L45-L49

Comment: That's just great, it works like a charm! I just checked the build_runner documentation and couldn't find it there. I guess it is within the JsonAnnotation-documentation? Thank you for the very quick response.

Comment: I also wondered why I couldn't find it in the API docs. This is why I searched the source.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when you use inheritance...

Comment: how to make it only ignore `toJson` method?

Comment: @buncis why would you want that? Methods are not serialized anyway.

Comment: pardon my language before, my use case is: there is `property` that I want transform from the json to my model but I want to ignore when I create the json from the model, hope this reply clarify it.

Comment: @buncis I think I got it, but I don't have a solution

Comment: @buncis Had the same need, found out the solution. Just add this key
`@JsonKey(toJson: null, includeIfNull: false)` - and this field will be removed from the `toJson` instruction.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore `super class's field` or ignore  `mixin's field` ?

Answer (score 6):

A workaround is to set the property to `null` and set `includeIfNull` flag to false:

```dart
toNull(_) => null;

@freezed
class User with _$User {
  const factory User({
    ...

    @Default(false)
    @JsonKey(toJson: toNull, includeIfNull: false)
        bool someReadOnlyProperty,
  }) = _User;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
}
```

And the generated code is:

```dart
/// user.g.dart

Map<String, dynamic> _$$_UserToJson(_$_User instance) {
  final val = <String, dynamic>{
    ...
  };

  void writeNotNull(String key, dynamic value) {
    if (value != null) {
      val[key] = value;
    }
  }

  writeNotNull('someReadOnlyProperty', toNull(instance.someReadOnlyProperty));
  return val;
}
```

Comment: I have checked this approach and it does not work. Receiving `The parameter someReadOnlyProperty of User is non-nullable but is neither required nor marked with @Default` @Andrey Gordeev

Comment: Also if anyone knows a valid solution related to Freeze, please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74171868

Comment: @genericUser did you forget to add `@Default`?

Comment: Yes! Thanks @Andrey Gordeev

Answer (score 0):

@JsonKey(includeFromJson: false, includeToJson: false)