# Flutter ignore field using Freezed

Tags: flutter, nsjsonserialization, flutter-freezed

I'm using Freezed to generate my models. I want to ignore a specific key, so I'm using @JsonKey(ignore: true).

```
@freezed
class ObjectA with _$ObjectA {
  const factory ObjectA({
    @JsonKey(ignore: true) 
    List<ObjectB> ObjectBList,
  }) = _ObjectA;

  factory ObjectA.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ObjectA(json);
}
```

When I try to run the build_runner, I'm getting the above exception:

> The parameter `ObjectBList` of `ObjectA.` is non-nullable but is neither required nor marked with @Default

Why doesn't it been ignored?

Comment: It works when I'm adding a dummy @Default value. But I think it should not fail if it's flagged ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is with `Dart` syntax. When you declare parameters in constructors.
You can have a `nullable` parameter or a `non-nullable` parameter; this also apply to variables.

If you want the parameter you declared in the constructor to be `non-nullable` then it must either have a default value or the declared parameter must be prefixed with the `required` keyword.

You have three options:

- Add the `required` keyword
  `required List<ObjectB> ObjectBList`
- Make it nullable
  `List<ObjectB>? ObjectBList`
- Give it a default value. With `freezed` this can be done with the `@Default` annotation
  `@Default([]) List<ObjectB> ObjectBList`

Comment: The `@JsonKey()` annotation is meant for serialization. It tells `json serializable` how to handle that parameter when building the `toJson` and `fromJson` methods

Comment: my list can be null. I tried to use Default([]) List list. But its giving error in freezed.g file. How can i handle this?

Comment: @HadiKhan If your list can be null, then you don't need a default value. You can remove the `Default([])`

Comment: Wont it throw error? Sometimes list is null for some json objects. I am not able to write a model like List list. I am forced to write List? list. When i want to display the list itme model.list!.item it will throw error that null check operator was used on null. model.list.item wont work

Comment: I don't understand. You should ask a new question describing in detail the challenge you are facing @HadiKhan